# How can I build only build release mode framework in flutter?

Tags: flutter, build, release

I create a fluter module and I want to build it into framework.
I use command:

***flutter build ios-framework***

everything works fine, I got  debug ,profile,release 3 modes content.
To save time, can I only build release mode?
***flutter build ios-framework --release*** not work.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no option to build a release mode for ios-framework. You can check the documentation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup).

Answer (score 2):

use --no-profile  --no-release flags

```
flutter build ios-framework --no-profile --no-release
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find some useful option when you use `flutter build ios-framework -h`

```
...

 --[no-]debug                     Whether to produce a framework for the debug build configuration. By default, all build configurations are built.
                                     (defaults to on)
 --[no-]profile                   Whether to produce a framework for the profile build configuration. By default, all build configurations are built.
                                     (defaults to on)
 --[no-]release                   Whether to produce a framework for the release build configuration. By default, all build configurations are built.
                                     (defaults to on)
...
```

So, you can use `flutter build ios-framework --no-debug --no-profile` to produce frameworks just for release mode